# Unable to process ActiveX event parameters in HTA using VBScript

Tags: vbscript, activex, hta

I am relatively new to HTAs and VBScript.  I am trying to duplicate some VBA functionality using an HTA and VBScript to eliminate the need for a VBA container, like MS Excel.

My application uses the iGrid V5.0 control.  I have the HTA working to display an instance of the grid and I can populate it.

The issue I am having is related to handling the iGrid event parameters.  I am using the RequestEdit event, which has a bCancel parameter passed by reference.  When using VBA, setting bCancel to True in the RequestEdit event disables editing for active column, which is the desired behavior.  I created the RequestEdit event in VBScript using ByRef for the bCancel parameter.  When the event executes, I set the bCancel parameter to True for certain grid columns (and verify this using MsgBox bCancel), but this value is not returned to the iGrid control.  All columns remain editable regardless of the value of bCancel.

Does this have to do with all VBScript variables/parameters being passed as Variants?  Any suggestions on what I need to do to successfully pass ByRef event parameter values back to the ActiveX control?

Below are my two code examples.  This first uses VBA and functions as intended, where the cell with a value of "Locked" cancels edits to remain locked, and the "Editable" cell allows updates:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub grdTest_RequestEdit(ByVal lRow As Long, ByVal lCol As Long, ByVal lCharCode As Long, bCancel As Boolean, sText As String, lMaxLength As Long, eTextEditOpt As iGrid500_10Tec.ETextEditFlags)

    bCancel = (lCol = 1)

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

    With grdTest
        .ColCount = 2
        .RowCount = 1
        .RowHeight(1) = 20
        .CellValue(1, 1) = "Locked"
        .CellValue(1, 2) = "Editable"
    End With

End Sub
```

This second example is my HTA code, where both cells remain editable.  I added the MsgBox command in the RequestEdit event to show the value of bCancel:

```
<head>
<title>Test iGrid</title>
<HTA:APPLICATION 
     APPLICATIONNAME="Test iGrid"
     SCROLL="yes"
     SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
     WINDOWSTATE="normal"
/>

<script type="text/VBScript">

Sub Window_OnLoad()

    With grdTest
        .ColCount = 2
        .RowCount = 1
        .RowHeight(1) = 20
        .CellValue(1, 1) = "Locked"
        .CellValue(1, 2) = "Editable"
    End With

End Sub

Sub grdTest_RequestEdit(ByVal lRow, ByVal lCol, ByVal lCharCode, ByRef bCancel, ByRef sText, ByRef lMaxLength, ByRef eTextEditOpt)

    bCancel = (lCol=1)
    Msgbox bCancel

End Sub

</script>
</head>

<body>
<body bgColor="C0C0C0">
<object id="grdTest" classid="clsid:3F7D8777-8E7B-4AD1-9A24-D453DC390BAD" codebase="iGrid500_10Tec.ocx" Width="800" Height="400">
</object><br>
</body>
```

Comment: Is there any code you can show?

Comment: Yes.  Below are two code examples.  This first sample is VBA which functions as intended, where the Locked cell disables editing and the editable cell can be modified:

Comment: Sorry - I didn't know how the comment option worked.  I added code to the original posting.  Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: It might help to define `Sub grdTest_RequestEdit` after the `OBJECT`. AFAIK, in order for event wire-up to take place, the `grdTest` name has to be known before the event handler is declared.